# How to make green bar above navigation float up in CSS

Tags: html, css

When I load this in my browser, the green bar shows up when I hover over a nav link but I want it to be like some websites like http//adworkmedia.com and have the green bar on hover float to the top right below the address bar. Mine hovers exactly over the text. Here is my HTML & CSS Code. Also if you can help me raise my login form a couple pixels that will help too!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="Site Description">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Site Keywords">
    <title>AffAttraction | Performance Based Marketing Network</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
          <h1>AffAttraction</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="advertisers.html">Advertisers</a></li>
            <li><a href="publishers.html">Publishers</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="header-login">
          <form action="publishers/login.php" method="post">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" class="btn_1">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: : 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

/* Global */
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;

}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Header */
 header {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   background-color: #418DD9;
   padding-top: 15px;
   min-height: 50px;
 }

 header a {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 16px;
 }

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

header nav {
  float: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header a:hover {
  border-top: #00FF1E 3px solid;
}

#header-login {
  float: right;
}

#header-login input {
  height: 25px;
  width: 112px;
  float: none;
}
```

Thanks if you can help me solve this :D I am new to CSS :P

Comment: Check snippet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect can be accomplished by using border on the containing element of the menu. Basically, on hover you create the border-top with the specified `border-width, border-style and border-color` or you specify all these things using shortened `border: border-width border-style border-color`.

Here's the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5av9mhrk/

Comment: Ive added a border but its still not going up.